# Using the TParser in the Classes unit to parse a filter string

Tags: delphi, parsing

I want to parse a filter string similar to the following:

```
((Field1 = 'red') and (field2 = 2)) or (Field3 between 1 and 5) or (field4 in ['up', 'down'])
```

I'd like to use the TParser in the Classes unit, but there does not seem to be much documentation or examples on it.

Comment: What is the question? Anyway, if you need to parse a filter string look for a real parser - TParser is just a (very specialized) lexer, and there is better / more complete code available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TParser is used by IDE to parse DFM  files into a binary format (ObjectTextToBinary). To my knowledge it only recognizes 5 tokens: (EOF, Symbol, String, Integer, Float). It is not general enough, but built for a special purpose. You would have to subclass it and change it's implementation for your needs. My opinion is that it's better to just write your own class/automata for your specific purpose. (It's not even a parser but a lexical tokeniser).

Comment: I agree, I used TParse in my DFM to Object Tree Convert, I built for converting BDE Components to DBX.  http://tinyurl.com/dfmparse